# Angular 2 - Custom Pipe with <T> to avoid losing intellisense in vscode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Before reading: there is nothing wrong in the code posted, this question is purely related to an intellisense "issue", or really a technical question.

> What I'm trying to do

Basically, I have an array of elements which I need to group by.
To accomplish such, I've taken an existing GroupBy filter found in stackoverflow, changed it to support an asyncronous source, and just placed it in my own project.
So far, so good.

However, because such a pipe has an `Array<any>` of a transform value, I was wondering whether it's possible to use a sort of `<T>` to avoid losing intellisense on my view.

The pipe source is:

```
@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Array<any>, field: string): Array<any> {
    // Async support
    // This will prevent pipes stack to throw a null pointer exception.
    if (value != null) {
      const groupedObj = value.reduce((prev, cur)=> {
        if(!prev[cur[field]]) {
          prev[cur[field]] = [cur];
        } else {
          prev[cur[field]].push(cur);
        }
        return prev;
      }, {});
      return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedObj[key] }));
    }
    else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Because such a pipe should be, **by definition**, a generic group by pipe, the `any` source is actually forcing me to lose intellisense when I'm using the pipe in my view.

Basically, doing, for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of myModelsArray | groupBy: 'category_id'">
   {{elem.key}}
</div>
```

Assuming that `myModelsArray` is an array of objects defined by a custom model:

```
// Just a model.
class MyModel {
  constructor(public id: number, public category_id: number; public name: string){}
}
```

The pipe above will return an `Array<any>`, hence the intellisense on the view is completely lost.

> The real question

I was wondering whether there is a way to use a generic `<T>` with pipes: using that, I should be able to keep the intellisense in my view.

Basically, I've tried to do such:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
export class GroupByPipe<T> implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Array<T>, field: string): Array<{
    key: any,
    value: Array<T>
  }> | Array<T> {
    // Async support
    if (value != null) {
      const groupedObj = value.reduce((prev, cur)=> {
        if(!prev[cur[field]]) {
          prev[cur[field]] = [cur];
        } else {
          prev[cur[field]].push(cur);
        }
        return prev;
      }, {});
      return Object.keys(groupedObj).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedObj[key] }));
    }
    else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

which, of course, does compile and works, but still **doesn't solve the intellisense issue**. The issue is that (of course) the variable loses the intellisense, as seen here (please note: the model is not the same as above, though the pipe source is). Note that I've forced ".key", but the intellisense can't resolve the variable type.

[image]

Instead, by **not** using the pipe, the result is as follow:

[image]

(also, not that it's that relevant, but this is the italian version of vscode).

If anyone wants to play with it a bit, I've made an online plunkr which can easily help to reproduce the issue on a local editor:

https://plnkr.co/edit/LkCv26PY1UTFXIGIx8wl?p=preview

the model already has models in it.

> A possible solution

Of course it would be easy enough to either extend the pipe forcing a custom model type or just defining a custom group by pipe defining a custom model, but I'm wondering whether I'm losing something or what I'm trying to do is just **not** intended to be done.